# How to render embedded html with multiple tags in react

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm embedding a request form. I want to click a button in react to open the form, then add a button to go back/exit. Ive added the HTML tags into index.html but I'm having a hard time with control. I toggle the display: none/block to get it to appear/ disappear which works fine (also have to toggle display for all of the react app so only the form is shown.).

The Html I'm trying to embed has 3 tags. I'm not able to find an answer of how to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML with multiple tags.

I've also just tried to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML twice and just gave the react div the needed reference id. No luck, just a blank white page.

```
<div id="f6f2802e-49e8-477b-b405-8b2b18dded97"></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://d3ey4dbjkt2f6s.cloudfront.net/assets/external/work_request_embed.css" />
<script src="https://d3ey4dbjkt2f6s.cloudfront.net/assets/static_link/work_request_embed_snippet.js" clienthub_id="f6f2802e-49e8-477b-b405-8b2b18dded97" form_url="https://clienthub.getjobber.com/client_hubs/f6f2802e-49e8-477b-b405-8b2b18dded97/public/work_request/embedded_work_request_form"></script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

12 hours of trying.
(https://codesandbox.io/s/l9qmrwxqzq)
This worked pretty much immediately. Once I found it.

```
'''
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Check if Helmet works as expected with script tags</h1>
      <p>Check console output - you will see $ is undefined</p>
      <Helmet>
        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <script>
          {`
            console.log('Test', typeof $);
          `}
        </script>
      </Helmet>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
'''
```

My final product

```
'''
import React from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

export default class Jobber extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Application" id="f6f2802e-49e8-477b-b405-8b2b18dded97">
        <Helmet>
            <div id="f6f2802e-49e8-477b-b405-8b2b18dded97"></div>
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            media="screen"
            href="https://d3ey4dbjkt2f6s.cloudfront.net/assets/external/work_request_embed.css"
          />
          <script 
            src="https://d3ey4dbjkt2f6s.cloudfront.net/assets/static_link/work_request_embed_snippet.js" clienthub_id="f6f2802e-49e8-477b-b405-8b2b18dded97" form_url="https://clienthub.getjobber.com/client_hubs/f6f2802e-49e8-477b-b405-8b2b18dded97/public/work_request/embedded_work_request_form"
            />

        </Helmet>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
'''
```